# macOS - Determine current wallpaper path

Tags: macos, beta-seed-program, wallpaper, mojave

I want to get current location of my macOS wallpaper. Is there a file or a command that will allow me to find this data?

I would prefer a way that would allow me to do it from the Terminal.

macOS: Mojave Public Beta

Comment: What version of macOS are you using?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This article from [OSXDaily.com](http://osxdaily.com) should be helpful:

[Show the Location Path of Current Wallpaper in Mac OS X](http://osxdaily.com/2011/11/20/show-the-location-path-of-current-wallpaper-in-mac-os-x/)

> 1. Type the following defaults write command:
>
> `defaults write com.apple.dock desktop-picture-show-debug-text -bool TRUE;killall Dock`
>
> 2. Go to the desktop to see the path printed over the wallpaper images
>
> [image]
>
> 3. After you’ve retrieved the desktop picture (use Command+Shift+G to bring up the Go To Folder window), or done what you have needed to do, you can hide the path text by using the following command:
>
> `defaults delete com.apple.dock desktop-picture-show-debug-text;killall Dock`

---

To determine the path for wallpaper via Terminal, execute the following:

`osascript -e 'tell app "finder" to get posix path of (get desktop picture as alias)'`

Comment: Thanks for your response. I've upvoted it as I didn't precise how I would like to get the data

Comment: Updated the answer to include command line to obtain the filesystem path.

Comment: Giving me `Not authorized to send Apple events to System Events.`. Any solution to that? I'm on Mojave :(

Comment: A little Google-Fo reveals that it's possibly a Automator bug in macOS Mojave. Works fine in macOS High Sierra. Links: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51299066/macos-mojave-automator-not-authorized-to-send-apple-events-to-system-events?rq=1 https://www.reddit.com/r/MacOSBeta/comments/8yvzll/bug_run_applescript_not_authorized_to_send_apple/

Comment: terminal command tells me the path to the picture on the primary monitor, but not my second or third external monitor, or different virtual desktops. How does one iterate desktops?

Comment: Using this on macOS Mojave. It did not work on Public Beta 4 because of permissions problems. With Public Beta 5 it gives `Can’t make missing value into type alias.`.