# Why my desktop displays location path of the chosen image?

Tags: macos, terminal, graphics, desktop

Without doing anything specific I have suddenly the location path of the desktop image written on my desktop like

**(3)/System/Library/CoreServices/DefaultDesktop.jpg**

On my 2nd Monitor it says
**(6)/System/Library** and so forth.

Its not clickable, changing the desktop image is changing the written path, but not the mentioning itself.
[image]

Any ideas?
My System
MBP 13" Mid 2018, (4 TB3 Ports and TouchBar)
2,7 GHz IC i7
16 B 2133 MHz LPDDR3
Intel Iris Plus Graphics 655 1536 MB
macOS High Sierra, 10.13.6 w/ security update 2020-003

Comment: See also https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/332334/macos-determine-current-wallpaper-path

Answer (score 3):

I don't know how you got this turned on accidentally, but you can remove it by entering these two lines in Terminal.app:

```
defaults delete com.apple.dock desktop-picture-show-debug-text

killall Dock
```

Comment: So this turns it on? `defaults write com.apple.dock desktop-picture-show-debug-text true`

Comment: I believe so. I actually used [Mac Pilot](https://www.koingosw.com/products/macpilot/) to test this. You need to restart the Dock afterwards with `killall Dock` after turning it on or off.